# How can I stop Winform Process?

Tags: c#, winforms, try-catch

if unexpected errors occur I want to keep my form in idle mode that where my programs get inputs. I have a try and catch block to catch wrong user entry, once the user enters wrong inputs. I want to pop up the message and stop the process till user enters correct inputs. My application is receiving the pop up message, but doesn't stop and continue with next process.

Comment: A user entering invalid text is *not* unexpected.  That's why you use TryParse() to convert text, it doesn't throw an exception.

Comment: @HansPassant what should I do?

Comment: You should post a better code snippet.  Or use TryParse().

Comment: There's no human involved here.  This can only fail when the database contains garbage data.  That's not a problem you can handle, you need a human to fix that for you.  So don't handle it, just make sure that you give good information about the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
bool inputCorrect = false;
while (!inputCorrect)
{
        try
        {            
           //Try some code
           inputCorrect = true;
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
           //MessageBox.Show("Wrong entery...Please correct!!")
        }
 }
```

Comment: is goes like infinite loop that showing my message box again and again when the entry is wrong?

Comment: @user2760129: Indeed. It only stops when the entry is correct.